# SQL vs. NoSQL for medium complexity search systems

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql, mean-stack

We're about to start developing a scheduling system and we're motivated to migrate from PHP to Node for the Backend, so it makes sense to also migrate from MySQL to MongoDB (or something similar), I'm not a very tech person, but I'm trying to help my team to make the choices here. All features of this system seem ok to be with either database, but one particular situation raised me concerns regarding performance:

Let's assume I have several doctors on my base, each one with their specialties and clinic locations and also with their time span to work on this system. They also already have some appointments scheduled for spread hours during the weeks.

One user fills the search form with:

- Their geolocalization (x,y);
- The search radius (ex.: 10miles);
- Specialization needed (ex.: dermatologist);
- Desired hour (ex.: 11am);

This search, for my old-school mindset, seems OK for a relational database, but a lot of work for non-relational, since their availability will be inside each doctor 'JSON', and not in a specific external 'table' for scheduling.

Do my concerns make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result with both `SQL` and `NoSQL` database. But the project you are talking about is more relational design. Example:- Doctor can visit multiple clinics. A patient has also related to the Clinic as well as the doctor. The best solution, in this case, is the hybrid approach where your primary database should be relational and for the reading operation, you can plug `NoSQL` database like `MongoDB` if required.

Answer (score 0):

@Rafael Souza

You should go with Relational schema design.

If you use NoSQL then in our case below are the points I want to convey

1. NoSQL will not be utilized fully at its best.
2. Developers will have to learn NoSQL and its frameworks.
3. There is a vast forum for SQL problems compare to NOSQL.
4. Database storage size would not big so SQL should do good.
5. Here you need to manage the relationship between Doctor and Clinics which is best suitable in SQL.

I should say that don't go with the Hybrid approach as it will be overhead for your design, any database type is alone capable of handling all the features.